# the default action of top tab navigation and also navigation.navigate is not working

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation, tabs, react-native-navigation

I am going to use top tab navigator but the default click action is not working.So I set my own action to tabPress function but `navigation.navigate()` action also is not working this is my code

```
import { Image, Vibration } from "react-native";
import { RootTabParamList } from "../types";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen";
import { Text } from "../components/Themed";
import FormDataScreen from "../screens/FormDataScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
export default () => {
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenListeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        tabLongPress: (e) => {
          Vibration.vibrate(100);
        },
        tabPress: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          navigation.navigate("Root", {
            screen: route.name,
          });
        },
      })}
      tabBarPosition="bottom"
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        // tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint,
        lazy: true,
        tabBarStyle: {
          elevation: 5,
          height: 100,
          borderRadius: 30,
          margin: 10,
          justifyContent: "center",
        },
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
          height: 0,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, marginTop: 5 }}>Profile</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Image
              style={{ tintColor: color, width: 28, height: 28 }}
              source={require("../assets/images/icons/user.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Data"
        component={FormDataScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, marginTop: 5 }}>Forms</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Image
              style={{ tintColor: color, width: 28, height: 28 }}
              source={require("../assets/images/icons/form.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: () => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, marginTop: 5 }}>Home</Text>
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Image
              style={{ tintColor: color, width: 28, height: 28 }}
              source={require("../assets/images/icons/home.png")}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

what can I do to fix this problem.
I searched many things on the internet but none of them worked for me.
Please help me to solve this problem.